# Function not defined when I try to define any type of function

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to get the absolute difference between 2 ranges if they have the same amount of elements

Tried rewriting as private and normal function but does not work

```
Function absDiff(rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range) As Single
Dim rng1Count As Long, rng2Count As Long

rng1Count = rng1.Count
rng2Count = rng2.Count

If rng1Count = rng2Count Then
    absDiff = SumProduct(Abs(rng1 - rng2))
Else
    MsgBox "Error, ranges are not the same size"
End If
End Function
```

I expect the function to take the absolute difference but it does not even run, it is defined on module1 and I am trying to call it to a sub in the same module

```
Sub calcAbsdiff()
Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range

Set rng1 = Range("A1:A10")
Set rng2 = Range("B1:B10")

rng1 = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 100)
rng2 = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 100)

MsgBox "The sum of the absolute difference is " & absDiff(rng1, rng2)

End Sub
```

Comment: Did you step through the code in debugging mode? What happens? Which statements in `calcAbsdiff` are executed? Any Error Message when you arrive (in debugging mode) at the call of `absDiff`?

Comment: What did you expect rng.count to return? A total sum or are you trying to count cells?

Comment: it gives me the error message noted above as soon as I try to execute in debugging mode

Comment: I'm trying to count cells to set up the if statement @JvdV

Comment: In your formula `Abs(rng1 - rng2)` as `rng1` and `rng2` are ranges (so no numeric values...) will not work. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

What I am understanding, try this one:

```
Public Function absDiff(rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range) As Single
Dim rng1Count As Long, rng2Count As Long, i As Long

rng1Count = rng1.Count
rng2Count = rng2.Count
absDiff = 0

If rng1Count = rng2Count Then
    For i = 1 To rng1Count
        absDiff = Abs(rng1(i).Value2 * rng2(i).Value2) + absDiff
    Next i
Else
    MsgBox "Error, ranges are not the same size"
    absDiff = "Error"
End If
End Function
```

It seems that he issue is that your calculation directly on range can not work, so just loop the SumProduct. You will get a #VALUE! error as result if the ranges are not matching. (If not it will be 0)

Check that Single will be enough for the Function.

Hope it helps!